# npm version from-git: set git one level up

Tags: git, npm, version

I'm completely new to this and couldn't find this answer: how do I setup npm to search for the git repository one level up?

```
.git
web/package.json
```

So in the `web` folder, I run `npm version from-git`

```
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\dev\repo\project\webui\.git'
```

Comment: This is really annoying. git itself knows how to traverse upwards. Clearly npm is off doing its own thing when it ought to just be using git.